# Netbeans fails to deploy web application on tomcat

Tags: java, servlets, deployment, netbeans, tomcat9

I am using **NetBeans IDE** for building Servlet Applications. When I build and try to deploy on Tomcat I get the following errors-

```
In-place deployment at D:\SpringBootProjects\Servlets\urlrewritingsample\build\web
Deployment is in progress...
deploy?config=file%3A%2FC%3A%2FUsers%2FAyush%2520Singh%2FAppData%2FLocal%2FTemp%2Fcontext1073696000555366189.xml&path=/urlrewritingsample
FAIL - Failed to deploy application at context path [/urlrewritingsample]
D:\SpringBootProjects\Servlets\urlrewritingsample\nbproject\build-impl.xml:1030: The module has not been deployed.
See the server log for details.
BUILD FAILED (total time: 0 seconds)
```

Tomcat log messages-

```
18-Jan-2023 08:19:54.047 SEVERE [http-nio-8080-exec-6] org.apache.catalina.startup.ExpandWar.copy Error copying [C:\Users\Ayush%20Singh\AppData\Local\Temp\context125052041248512568.xml] to [C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 9.0\conf\Catalina\localhost\urlrewritingsample.xml]
    java.io.FileNotFoundException: C:\Users\Ayush%20Singh\AppData\Local\Temp\context125052041248512568.xml (The system cannot find the path specified)
        at java.base/java.io.FileInputStream.open0(Native Method)
        at java.base/java.io.FileInputStream.open(FileInputStream.java:216)
        at java.base/java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:157)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.ExpandWar.copy(ExpandWar.java:269)
        at org.apache.catalina.manager.ManagerServlet.deploy(ManagerServlet.java:1006)
        at org.apache.catalina.manager.ManagerServlet.doGet(ManagerServlet.java:357)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:670)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:779)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:227)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162)
        at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162)
        at org.apache.catalina.filters.HttpHeaderSecurityFilter.doFilter(HttpHeaderSecurityFilter.java:126)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:177)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:97)
        at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:660)
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.RequestFilterValve.process(RequestFilterValve.java:378)
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.RemoteAddrValve.invoke(RemoteAddrValve.java:56)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:135)
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92)
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:687)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:78)
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:360)
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:399)
        at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:65)
        at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:891)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1784)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1191)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:659)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
        at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:833)
```

Can somebody please explain the reason for this error and how to resolve it?

Answer (score 0):

Here the problem is with the User Profile Folder's Name.
The space in that folder's name (Ayush Singh) creates a problem.
I'm not sure that is windows error or netbeans error but try running netbeans into other user account with name which does not have space or other special characters in between like Ayush.
This was the error with me as well and I tried above steps and it worked.